# how to proxy an interface using spring like spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring

there is on interface and no implementation.

Interface Test{

```
@MyAnnotation
pubilc void sayHello();
```

}

and i want to using spring to proxy that and let it can be autowired in other beans ,like

Class App{

@Autowired 
   Test test;

}

and in some proxy class i will handle invoke of 'sayHello' by some custom actions according to its annotation .

so how to config the spring xml file and how to write some "MethodInvokeHandler" class ?

i want to add some configuration to spring xml and assign "base-package" to scan these interface and generate the auto proxy code into spring context , so i can use @autowired to inject them to other bean .

Answer (score 0):

This function is no standard spring functionality, so you can not configurate, you have to implement it.

But Java supports you with the [Dynamic Proxy API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html), and its core class [`Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).